# ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android

I have an activity class along with customlistadapter inside **customlist adapter**.
 I have a thread `runouithread` which give me error msg when i wrap it with `((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`.
it throws the error msg at runtime has `ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`.
 So please some one help me.

```
public class CustomListAdapterfriend extends BaseAdapter  {
List<HashMap<String, Object>> models; 
   Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

URL urll;
HttpURLConnection connection;

  InputStream input;

  ViewHolder viewHolder;
//UI for Locations
ImageView pic,image,delam;
TextView name,timestamp,msg,url,idas,idas2,emasr,cn;
ArrayList<String> listItems;
ListView lv;
public int count1 = 0;
 ProgressDialog pDialog;
//String session_email="",session_type="",share_app,share_via;
private String stringVal;
private int mCounter1=1;
private int counter=0;
public int temp=0;
String con, pros;
private int[] counters;
int pos;
int width,height;
int position2;
 String id,emm;
Transformation transformation;
//ImageButton sharingButton;
String pacm,session_email,session_ph,session_type,session_loc,connter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> usersList,usersList1;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
int i ;



JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
static String IP = IpAddress.Ip;
private String imagePath = IP+"/social/upload/";
//url to create new product
public static String add_wish = IP+"/studio/add_wishlist.php";
private static String url_all_properties5 = IP+"/social/get_all_agen_like.php";
private static String url_all_properties1 = IP+"/social/get_lik_coun.php";
private static String url_all_properties6 = IP+"/social/get_all_agen_like3.php";
private static String url_all_properties7 = IP+"/social/get_all_dele_like.php";
private static String url_all_properties8 = IP+"/social/get_all_dele_uplike.php";
  boolean isSelected;
  int a,a1,b,b1;

    //private static final String TAG_SUCCESS1 = "mass";
    private static final String TAG_USER = "users";

    private static final String TAG_PRO = "properties";
    //private static final String TAG_PRO1 = "properties1";
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray users = null;
    //JSONArray users1 = null;
     View view;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
 SharedPreferences sPref;
// int position;


public CustomListAdapterfriend(Context context, List<HashMap<String, Object>> models) {
    this.context = context;
    this. models = models;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.counters = new int[30];

    //this.session_email = sPref.getString("SESSION_UID","");

}

public class ViewHolder {

       public TextView countt,idas5,emasr,cn;

      // public String id,emm;

       public  ImageView like;
       public ImageView share;
    /*public void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/



    }

public void clear(){
    if(models!=null)
        models.clear();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return models.size();
}

public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int position) {
    return models.get(position);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
} 

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public View getView( final int position, final View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        //  view = null;
      view = convertView;

      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

          sPref= context.getSharedPreferences("REAL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        session_email = sPref.getString("SESSION_UID","");
        session_ph = sPref.getString("SESSION_PH","");
        session_type = sPref.getString("SESSION_TYPE", "");
        session_loc = sPref.getString("SESSION_LOC", "");
      //  lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        pos = getItemViewType(position);
      //  long posn = getItemId(position);
     // final int paps= (int)posn ;
        if (view == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home2, parent, false);
            //your code




            //add below code after (end of) your code
            viewHolder.idas5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hpid);
            viewHolder. emasr= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ema);
            viewHolder.like=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.likem);

            viewHolder.share=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.sharemsp);

            viewHolder.cn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);


            viewHolder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     int position = (Integer) v.getTag();



                      HashMap<String, Object> item = models.get(position);
                      String imagePath = (String)item.get("IMAGE").toString();

                    try {
                        urll = new URL(imagePath);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    try {
                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) urll.openConnection();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                      connection.setDoInput(true);

                      try {
                        connection.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        input = connection.getInputStream();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                      Bitmap immutableBpm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                      if(immutableBpm !=null)
                      {

                      Bitmap mutableBitmap = immutableBpm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);



                      View view  = new View(context);

                      view.draw(new Canvas(mutableBitmap));

                      String path = Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), mutableBitmap, "Nur", null);
                      Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);


                     /* image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
                      Drawable mDrawable = image.getDrawable();
                      Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();
                      Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                      share.setType("image/*");
                      String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "Image Description", null);

                      Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);*/
                      Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                      share.setType("image/*");
                      share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

                      context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
                      }
                      else
                      {

                          Toast.makeText(context, "No image to share", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                      }

                }


            });


           // viewHolder.share.setOnItemClickListener(this);


            viewHolder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like1);

            viewHolder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                   // viewHolder.countt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count);
                    HashMap<String, Object> item = models.get(position);

                    viewHolder.idas5.setText((CharSequence) item.get("UIDAS"));

                    // id=(String) viewHolder.idas5.getText();
                     viewHolder.emasr.setText((CharSequence) item.get("EMAILM"));

                        id=(String) viewHolder.idas5.getText();

                        emm=(String) viewHolder.emasr.getText();



                         new LoadAllProducts().execute(); 


                          new LoadAllProducts22().execute(); 


                          notifyDataSetChanged();




                    /*if( viewHolder.like.isSelected()){
                         viewHolder.like.setSelected(false);
                        //viewHolder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like2);

                         new LoadAllProducts7().execute(); 
                         new LoadAllProducts22().execute();
                         notifyDataSetChanged();
                     }


                     else if(!viewHolder.like.isSelected()){
                         viewHolder.like.setSelected(true);
                            //ctv.setBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor("#d2d0d0"));
                        // viewHolder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like1);

                            new LoadAllProducts().execute(); 
                              new LoadAllProducts22().execute(); 
                              notifyDataSetChanged();

                     }*/


                }
            });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.like.setTag(position);  
         viewHolder.share.setTag(position);





     final HashMap<String, Object> item = getItem(position);
   /*         name.setText(((String)item.get(R.id.name)));
     * 
    * 
    */        
     new LoadAllProducts78().execute(); 


   //  boolean  isSelected = (Boolean) item.get("selected");





       /*if (viewHolder.like.isSelected()) {

         viewHolder.like.setSelected(false);
         viewHolder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like2);





       } else if (!viewHolder.like.isSelected()){

         viewHolder.like.setSelected(true);
            //ctv.setBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor("#d2d0d0"));
         viewHolder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like1);



       }  */




     pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
     name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
     idas = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hpid);

     idas2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hpid2);
     timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
     msg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
     url = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
     image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);



     idas.setText((CharSequence) item.get("UIDAS"));

     viewHolder.cn.setText((CharSequence) item.get("COUN"));
    // listItems.add(idas.getText().toString());
     name.setText((CharSequence) item.get("NAME"));
     timestamp.setText((CharSequence) item.get("TIME"));
     msg.setText((CharSequence) item.get("MSG"));
     url.setText((CharSequence) item.get("URL"));









     //countt.setText((CharSequence) item.get("COUN"));
     //count.setText("" + count1);


     int w = image.getWidth();
     int h = image.getHeight();

     if (w > 1000)
     {
          a=w-1000;
          b=w-a;
     }

     else
     {
         b=w;
     }


     if (h > 1000)
     {
          a1=h-1000;
          b1=h-a1;
     }

     else
     {
         b1=h;
     }

        Picasso.with(context)
        //.load("PIC")
     .load((String)item.get("PIC"))
        .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_dummy)
        //.error(R.drawable.ic_whats_hot)
        .resize(50, 50)
      // .centerCrop()
       // .fit()
        .into(pic);



        /*Display display =  getActivity().getWindowManager().
            getDefaultDisplay();                                                                                                                
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size); 
        int width = size.x;*/



     Picasso.with(context)
     .load((String)item.get("IMAGE"))

    //.load("IMAGE")
    // .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_pages)
     //.error(R.drawable.ic_home)
      .resize(1000,image.getHeight())
        .onlyScaleDown()
       //.centerCrop()
      // .fit().centerInside()
     .into(image);









        return view;
        }

       protected ContentResolver getContentResolver() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
        }


          class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading.. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();*/



        /*Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                pDialog.cancel();
            }
        };

        Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
        pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);*/

    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
      //  session_email = sPref.getString("SESSION_UID","");

        usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        //usersList1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();


        // id=(String) viewHolder.idas5.getText();

        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {

            try {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", session_email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loc", "liked"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("con", "1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idtes", id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emas", emm));


            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_properties5,                "GET", params);

             if (json != null) {

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All start: ", json.toString());
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);



            if (success== 1) {



                Log.d("Inside success...", json.toString());
                connter = json.getString("loca");


                Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                 sPref.edit().putString("SESSION_UID", session_email).commit();
                    sPref.edit().putString("SESSION_TYPE", session_type).commit();
                    sPref.edit().putString("SESSION_PH", session_ph).commit();
                    sPref.edit().putString("SESSION_LOC", session_loc).commit();
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
                    ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    ((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);
                 ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);


                //Toast.makeText(context, "Already liked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            } 

            else if (success== 5){
                // no products found


                Toast.makeText(context, "Already liked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }


             } else {



                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             }
        }); 


        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        //pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread


    //  pDialog.dismiss();

    }





}







         class LoadAllProducts78 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Friendsprofile.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading.. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
    */


    /*Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog.cancel();
        }
    };

    Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
    pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);*/

}

/**
 * getting All products from url
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
  //  session_email = sPref.getString("SESSION_UID","");

    //usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    //usersList1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();


    // id=(String) viewHolder.idas5.getText();

    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

            try {


    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", session_email));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emas", emm));


        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_properties6, "POST", params);

         if (json != null) {

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All bastart: ", json.toString());
        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG

        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);



        if (success== 1) {


            viewHolder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like1);
            viewHolder.like.setSelected(true);




        } 

        else if(success == 2) {

            viewHolder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like2);
        }


         } else {



            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
   });



    return null;
}


/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    //pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread


    //pDialog.dismiss();

}





    }












     class LoadAllProducts22 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    /*
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading.. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();



    Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog.cancel();
        }
    };

    Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
    pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);*/

}

/**
 * getting All products from url
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
  //  session_email = sPref.getString("SESSION_UID","");



    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();





        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_properties1, "GET", params);

         if (json != null) {

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Productgetting start: ", json.toString());
        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);



        if (success== 1) {



        } 

        else {
            // no products found
            // Launch Add New product Activity
            /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),    MainActivity.class);
            // Closing all previous activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);*/
        }

         } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         } else {



            }





    return null;
}



/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    //pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread




}





     }




        class LoadAllProducts7 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    /*
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading.. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();



    Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog.cancel();
        }
    };

    Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
    pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);*/

}

/**
 * getting All products from url
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
  //  session_email = sPref.getString("SESSION_UID","");

    usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    //usersList1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();


    // id=(String) viewHolder.idas5.getText();




    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", session_email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loc", "liked"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("con", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idtes", id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emas", emm));


        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_properties7, "GET", params);

         if (json != null) {

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All start: ", json.toString());
        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);



        if (success== 1) {




             // new LoadAllProducts22().execute();



            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products

            /*users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRO);

            //users1 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRO1);


            // looping through All Products


            for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);
                //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);



                // Storing each json item in variable
                //String scpass = countt.getText().toString();
                String uid = c.getString("uid1"); //from php blue



                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put("UIDAS", uid); //from 
                map.put("PIC", pic);

                usersList.add(map);
                //usersList1.add(map);


                // creating new HashMap


            }*/


        } 

        else {
            // no products found
            // Launch Add New product Activity
            /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),    MainActivity.class);
            // Closing all previous activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);*/
        }

         } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         } else {



            }





    return null;
}


/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    //pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread




}





      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because while calling this constructor:

```
CustomListAdapterfriend(Context context, List<HashMap<String, Object>> models)
```

You are providing `getApplicationContext()`. Try to provide `context` of the `activity`.

Edit 1:

Following the comments:

```
CustomListAdapterfriend adapter = new CustomListAdapterfriend(Friendsprofile.this, usersList); lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Sorry But how to provide context of the activity and where

Comment: can you update the code where you are calling the above constructor. BTW, you can do that by calling something like `MainActivity.this`, where `MainActivity` is the name of your `activity`.

Comment: CustomListAdapterfriend adapter = new CustomListAdapterfriend(getApplicationContext(),  usersList);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter); this the code which i used in mainactivity to connect with custom list adapter class

Comment: Is this inside an `activity` or `fragment`?

Comment: activity class named as public class Friendsprofile extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener and customlist adapter another class

Comment: hey rohith thanks its working fine...so is it with fragment getapplication and with activity classname.this

Comment: with fragments, use `getActivity()` not `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @AnishYesudasan, if it solved your problem, can you [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the constructor of your adapter class from

```
public CustomListAdapterfriend(Context context, List<HashMap<String, Object>> models)
```

to

```
public CustomListAdapterfriend(Activity context, List<HashMap<String, Object>> models)
```

So whenever you call the constructor, the IDE will notify you to provide an Activity as a parameter, so the cast in your adapter won't fail.

Comment: when i do so it gives me an error msg at main activity where i had provided the code to link custom list adapter CustomListAdapterfriend adapter = new CustomListAdapterfriend(getApplicationContext(),  usersList);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);  it says it is undefined

Comment: Because getApplicatipnContext() doesn't return an Activity. You should change it to Friendsprofile.this

Answer (score 0):

While using in fragments try `requireActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

`CustomListAdapterfriend(requireActivity(), List<HashMap<String, Object>> models)`